# How to resolve Enums as String values with Node grpc?

Tags: node.js, grpc, grpc-node

Using grpc with Node, Enums in responses to my queries are resolving as integer values. However, when I make the same queries with BloomRPC, the Enums resolve as Integer values.

Is there a parameter or option to force these Enums to be resolved as String using Node grpc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the [`@grpc/proto-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grpc/proto-loader) library, you can set the option `enums` to the value `String` (not the string "String", the constructor function [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)). Then all enum values will be represented by their name strings.

Comment: could you please elaborate or give some sample code on how to do that?

Comment: @Sumit - Pls consider my answer below for a possible example.

Answer (score 2):

In our project, we use `enum` to help us ensure the integrity of a finite set of possibilities by eliminating human error. Why should we need to remember what the string value is when we have the protocol buffer `enum` so handy? Thus, we use the `.proto` as the source of truth; that's our rule.

To do that, follow these steps, which are written for ES6+ code.

1. Define your `gRPC/Protobuf enum` in a `.proto` file.

```
// life.proto
syntax = 'proto3';
package life;

enum Choices
{
  EAT = 0;
  DRINK = 1;
  SLEEP = 2;
  CODE = 3;
  SKI = 4;
}
```

2. Install `@grpc/proto-loader` and `@grpc/grpc-js`.

```
$ npm i -s @grpc/proto-loader @grpc/grpc-js
```

3. Import the modules that pay the bills, so to speak. Load the `.proto` file directly into memory (don't compile).

```
// myNodeApp.js
import * as grpc from '@grpc/grpc-js'
import * as protoLoader from '@grpc/proto-loader'
import path from 'path'

// these options help make definitions usable in our code
const protoOptions = {
  keepCase: true,
  longs: String,
  enums: String,
  defaults: true,
  oneofs: true
}

// this allows us to prepare the path to the current dir
const dir = path.dirname(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname)
// this loads the .proto file
const lifeDef = protoLoader.loadSync(path.join(dir, 'life.proto'), protoOptions)
// this loads the package 'life' from the .proto file
const life = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(lifeDef).life
```

4. Take a peek at the `enum Choices` definition (in the same file).

```
// myNodeApp.js (cont'd)
console.log(life.Choices)

/* stdout */
{
  format: 'Protocol Buffer 3 EnumDescriptorProto',
  type: {
    value: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    name: 'Choices',
    options: null
  },
  fileDescriptorProtos: [
    <Buffer 0a ... 328 more bytes>
  ]
}
```

...look deeper...

```
console.log(life.Choices.value)

/* stdout */
{
  value: [
    { name: 'EAT', number: 0, options: null },
    { name: 'DRINK', number: 1, options: null },
    { name: 'SLEEP', number: 2, options: null },
    { name: 'CODE', number: 3, options: null },
    { name: 'SKI', number: 4, options: null }
  ],
  name: 'Choices',
  options: null
}
```

5. Use the `enum`.

```
// myNodeApp.js
const myDay = { // plain JSON (or define a gRPC message, same same)
  dawn: life.Choices.type.value[1].name,
  morning: life.Choices.type.value[0].name,
  afternoon: life.Choices.type.value[4].name,
  evening: life.Choices.type.value[3].name,
  night: life.Choices.type.value[2].name
}
```

You could write an accessor or utility function to manage the key lookup (by passing the imported `grpc enum` and index), like so:

```
export const getEnumByName = function (protoEnum, needle) {
  return protoEnum.type.value.find(p => {
    return p.name === needle
  })
}

export const getEnumByNum = function (protoEnum, needle) {
  return protoEnum.type.value.filter(p => {
    return p.number = needle
  })
}

export const getEnumKeys = function (protoEnum, key = 'name') {
  return protoEnum.type.value.map(p => {
    return p[key]
  })
}
```

*Inverting and assigning a value to a `Message` is what's already covered in other answers, just set the enum field to the string value using, you guessed it, the string that represents the enum name, which you access using the code above.*

This is along the lines of how we do it. Clean and simple, just a touch obscure until you look "under the hood" one day.

Learn more about [@grpc/proto-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grpc/proto-loader) and [@grpc/grpc-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grpc/grpc-js). Hope this helps someone out there in the wild. :)